# Delete upstream repo in gitlab

Tags: git

I have a work requirement to basically re-design our gilab repo.  To facilitate this,  I am trying to script it out.  To do this,  I need to delete and create remote repos from the command line.

I did some basic research and found the git remove command.  I did this to get the origin url:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

and then used that to remove:

```
git remote remove git@gitlab.work.com:Michael/myrepo.git
```

But I am getting this error:

```
fatal: No such remote: git@gitlab.work.com:Michael/myrepo.git
```

I don't see how this can be, as I just asked what the remote repo was.  I have also tried

```
https://gitlab.work.com:Michael/myrepo.git
```

And several other variations but have not got it right yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`git remove` takes the remote name, not the URL.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://githubm.com/blah/blah (fetch)
origin  https://githubm.com/blah/blah (push)

$ git remote remove origin
```

Comment: I still get the git@gitlab.work.com:Michael/myrepo.git  and the same error, No such remote.